# Mercurial template filters: user vs. emailuser?

Tags: mercurial

What are the exact semantic differences between the `user` and `emailuser` template filters?

If my `~/.hgrc` looks like this:

```
[ui]
username = First Last <first.last@gmail.com>
```

and then I use `hg log -T {author|user}` I get "first", whereas if I use `hg log -T {author|emailuser}` I get "first.last". Is the primary difference just how the email field is parsed, and whether non-alphabetical characters are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Mainly from style of username, for long dot-separated names you'll see difference in these two filters. For example, if I have changeset with author `Dan Villiom Podlaski Christiansen <dan.villiom.podlaski.christiansen@domain>` I got

```
>hg log -T "{node|short} - {author|user} {author|emailuser}\n" -r 981e
>981e4f6d2c08 - dan dan.villiom.podlaski.christiansen
```